# Console for live scripting against .NET

Tags: c#, scripting

I'm building an application to do build some charts using MSChart or similar .NET library and have a domain model managing data from an EF Context and we've been gathering data and want to start doing some analyses and plot results on the carts.  What would be nice is to have a panel in our app where we could tap into the loaded data writing lines of code or full blown scripts to do complex analysis and dump the results on the chart.

One option that would be nice is if something like JavaScript could be integrated and run from a console attached to the running UI process. I recall from the C++ framework Qt that it has an ECMA style language library bound into their C++ API which allows developers to provide end users the ability to script against the C++ types. An added bonus if this is possible would be the ability to have it use TypeScript to allow the advanced features like classes, async and LINQ style expressions.

Another option could be along the lines of having the ability to just write C# in the editor panel and have it compile against the running in memory assemblies and return the results to the panel process to render results in the Chart. Having intellisense would be a major bonus as well.

Does anyone know if there's something for .NET (C#) that provides these type of integration or have any suggestions on which building blocks would help to start me in the right direction?

Comment: You can do scripting in C# in many languages like C# itself, Lua, Boo, IronPython, Javascript, etc. For example, using [V8.NET](https://github.com/rjamesnw/v8dotnet), [NLua](http://nlua.org/), [Boo](https://boo-language.github.io/), etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [Jint](https://github.com/sebastienros/jint) looks like the best option. Provides simple binding of javascript to .NET types and methods.